# Reaction of HBr + 2,4-dimethylpent-1,3-diene yields 3 products?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My understanding is that either pi bond can react with HBr but that you still have to follow Marovnikov's rule or whatever.

I end up with 2 allylic carbocations that are actually the same molecule along with 1 unformed non allylic carbonation. From there there is only one product...

Comment: What's wrong with having only one product?

Comment: My exam said list all 3 products created.

Comment: Maybe they just wanted you to list all the theoretically possible products. But that is a problem with your exam paper, you yourself don't really seem to have a problem.

Comment: But what would be the 3 theoretical products? I feel like I did the problem wrong or something.. he definitely made it sound as if there are 3 products formed. Which doesn't make sense because I ended up with 2 equivalent molecules and a 3rd unformed unstable carbocation. Are there other products I'm missing?